# Image from url to PDF

Tags: python-3.x, cloudinary

How can I convert **images saved on cloudinary to pdf** using their url with python3 + django?
I tried using pdfkit but it's not fetching the image from url and creates a blank pdf.

Comment: download the image locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the format to pdf, like this:

https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/f_pdf/bike.jpg

Python:

```
CloudinaryImage("bike.jpg").image(fetch_format="pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the helpful answers.
I used **urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)** to download the images from the urls to local system and then with the help of **PyFPDF** converted them to the pdf file.

Link: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html